# jQuery animate complete doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: jquery

```
console.log('1');
jQuery('#inner-content').animate({
    'width': jQuery('#inner-content-wrapper').width() + 'px'
}, {
    duration: 800,
    queue: false,
    complete: function(){
        console.log('2');
    }
});
console.log('3');
```

Console output **Chrome v28**: 1,3,2

Console output **Firefox v23**: 1,3
Animation works but complete is never executed, this also doesn't work in IE 10

HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="inner-content-wrapper" class="wrap clearfix">
        <div id="inner-content" class="wrap clearfix">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Computed Style **content**

```
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
display: block;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
height: 243px;
line-height: 24px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 70px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
width: 1756px;
```

Computed Style **inner-content-wrapper**

```
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
display: block;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
height: 243px;
line-height: 24px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 378px;
margin-right: 378px;
margin-top: 0px;
max-width: 1000px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
width: 1000px;
zoom: 1;
```

Computed Style **inner-wrapper**

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85098);
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
display: block;
float: right;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
height: 243px;
line-height: 24px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
max-width: 1000px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 50px;
position: relative;
width: 1000px;
zoom: 1;
```

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome and FF http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/VB3CS/

Comment: Can you post your HTML? Works fine for me as well.

Comment: If people are reporting it works, console log other bits of your code to make sure it's all firing in firefox. I just fixed a jquery firefox bug that didn't throw any errors, but my code was technically wrong. Once i fixed it it worked as expected in all browsers.

Comment: I'm not sure what good my HTML code will be to you without the css, how should I post this? @shan I'm sure it doesnt fire, there were statements in there that I took out to make this question shorter